# How can I detect nearby GameObjects without physics/raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to detect the object's within a range having the player as origin point.
How can I find the `Transforms` from a given area around the player without using colliders or `Physics.OverlaptSphere()` I don't want to use this method because the only information I need is the Transform of nearby Objects from a given `LayerMask` (more specifically, the position and rotation) If I would use Physics I would have to put a trigger over every point which I find unnecessary.

Is there other method of finding the nearby points other but similar to the one that uses Physics?

Comment: you are the master of your game universe. you should be able to get them all. compute the distance from your player to the desired objects and you are set - this is the brute force way. you could attach a script to your desireable updates and let it compute the distance to the player, if it is below a threshold you notify some bookkeeper object that you are "inside the sphere of influence of player" - the bookkeeper checks its internal list on update and removes things that got out of this spehere ... etc. Think about it and code it.

Comment: Isan't using Vector3.Distance for many points expensive?

Comment: You could throw raycasts around the player and see what they hin in distance xyz. If you decided on a aproach, and get problems, show us code.

Comment: Or not even that...I did think about that to but I just wante to know if it is a solution similar to Physics.Overlap(); but without using Physics

Comment: Why? Vector,distance is ver very very simple math, that is what computers are good at. Raycast is more complicated math, so I wouldnt resort to that. Sphere of influence decides on overlap of (I presume) bounding volumes - thats more complicated then calculating the distance between 2 3d points.

Comment: Do you have millions of objects? from the layermask I gathered there wont be many objects so you should be fine. Code it, try it, if its too slow, post code and get help optimizing it.

Comment: Hmm...ok! That is a satisfaying response. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want yo do this without Physcics or Colliders, access all the objects. Loop through them, check the layer and if they match, use `Vector3.Distance` to compare the distance of each object. Return the result.

```
List<GameObject> findNearObjects(GameObject targetObj, LayerMask layerMask, float distanceToSearch)
{
    //Get all the Object
    GameObject[] sceneObjects = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

    List<GameObject> result = new List<GameObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < sceneObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        //Check if it is this Layer
        if (sceneObjects[i].layer == layerMask.value)
        {
            //Check distance
            if (Vector3.Distance(sceneObjects[i].transform.position, targetObj.transform.position) < distanceToSearch)
            {
                result.Add(sceneObjects[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This can be improved by using `Scene.GetRootGameObjects` to retrieve all the `GameObjects` but it does not return Objects that are marked as `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Extended as extension function:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static List<GameObject> findNearObjects(this GameObject targetObj, LayerMask layerMask, float distanceToSearch)
    {
        GameObject[] sceneObjects = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        List<GameObject> result = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sceneObjects.Length; i++)
            if (sceneObjects[i].layer == layerMask.value)
                if (Vector3.Distance(sceneObjects[i].transform.position, targetObj.transform.position) < distanceToSearch)
                    result.Add(sceneObjects[i]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<GameObject> sceneObjects = gameObject.findNearObjects(layerMask, 5f);
```